# Elasticsearch cluster discovery - Unicast hosts

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, discovery

I can't seem to find this in the docs.

When I specify `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` do I need to specify every node in the cluster? I'm hoping that I can specify a subset of the nodes, and the node will discover the cluster through whatever protocol they're using (gossip?). Will it use the `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` for master election, or will it use whatever state it's aware of?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's enough to specify the master-eligible nodes. Since every node in the cluster should know the entire cluster setup (through the cluster state), a new node joining the cluster will "ask" the nodes from the `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` list to share the cluster state. From this it will learn of all other nodes' whereabouts.

Comment: so, just to clarify; I only need to specify a subset of the hosts, and newly joining nodes will get the cluster state from those nodes

Comment: Yes. I said master eligible nodes because those are most likely to be available. You can imagine that when a node joins it needs to have nodes from which it can learn.